# How to Exclude Specific Content by Tag in Django RSS Feed

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I'd like to exclude specific articles from my feed based on their tag.

In the following case I'd like to exclude all articles that are tagged **Exclude Article**.

**model.py**

```
tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag, blank=True, related_name='tagged')
```

**feed.py**

```
def items(self, item):
    return Article.published().all().exclude(tags__name=["Exclude Article"])[:5]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try:

```
return Article.published().all().exclude(tags__name="Exclude Article")[:5]
```